# Using both Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider and Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider

Tags: serialization, session-state, outputcache, redis-cache

I have installed and used Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider for a while and after looking at OutputCaching I thought of installing Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider as well but they both have Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer interface which breaks my JsonCacheSerializer as it uses the ISerializer interface.

I am getting an error in VS 2017, which reads ...

"**The type 'ISerializer' exists in both Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider and Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider**"

The JsonCacheSerializer code I use for SessionState is :

```
public class JsonCacheSerializer : Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
        Error = (serializer, err) => {
            err.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    };

    public byte[] Serialize(object data)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Settings));
    }

    public object Deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        return data == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data), Settings);
    }
}
```

Does this mean one has to use one or the other, not both?

Answer (score 0):

You may use extern alias feature of C# 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias

Visual Studio example: 
1) right click Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider and put following into Aliases field:

```
global,redisoutputcacheprovider
```

2) right click Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider and put following into Aliases field:

```
global,redissessionstateprovider
```

then on top of your code file add:

```
extern alias redissessionstateprovider;
extern alias redisoutputcacheprovider;
```

and finally declare your class as:

```
public class JsonCacheSessionStateSerializer : redissessionstateprovider::Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer
```